# java thread issue with cassandra

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, cassandra

I am using java8 and cassandra 2.1.14. I am developing a TCP/IP socket application in java. I have some devices on the network which ping my java service on a specific port. I have to read data from the devices based on the commands given to the devices from the UI that get stored in the database. My server picks commands from the database on regular interval and process the commands. Problem is that, after a certain duration thread count of my application keeps on increasing and java application goes out of memory in heap. I have looked through my code but i don't see any issue with code. I came to know from somewhere that cassandra version has some issue because of which application goes out of memory.

Comment: Try adding some more specifics here around your question, for example: 1) sample of how your program sets up the connection to cassandra, 2) what driver version your using the connect to cassandra, 3) how you monitor the thread count, 4) where you are seeing the OOM condition, 5) topology of your cluster from `nodetool status`

Comment: Is it java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread: Error which you are getting?

Comment: yes. same OutOfMemoryError